# Can we place background color and then text on the UIButton using CALayer?

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-animation

I have a UIButton and I want to place the background color first and then the text label. I tried this using the CALayer but couldn't succeed.

Is there any way to achieve this using CALayer or not?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's my try out:

```
//creating sublayer
    CALayer *yellowLayer = [CALayer layer];
    yellowLayer.frame = CGRectMake(rec_Xoffset, 2, width, height-4);
    yellowLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    [label setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
    [label setFontSize:20];
    [label setFrame:button1.frame];
    [label setString:@"Hello"];
    [label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [label setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [yellowLayer insertSublayer:label above:yellowLayer];

    label.zPosition=10.0;

    [button1.layer addSublayer:yellowLayer];
```

Could anyone enlight me in this core animation layers? I guess this is the result of little knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by placing first?

Comment: @iDev, i have a button where i first want to put the background color and then put the text over it . I mean to say the hierarchy.

Comment: you want the delay between transition?

Comment: Why do you want to use a CALayer for this? Why not set the backgroundColor of the button and its title?

Comment: @ rdelmar - I have the condition to set the background color on the button only in some area of button. So i didn't find setting the background color of the button and title fit for me?? More precisely , I 'm setting the color stripes in my button based on my condition.

Comment: to set background color use `[btnPlayAudio setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];` and for title `[btnPlayAudio setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`. i think same as @rdelmar. maybe you dnt need to use `CALayer`.

Comment: @Chinttu'RoxeN'Ramani, can we set the background color in the button by specifying the frame.If there is, then also, it won't fit my condition to set the stripes background based on my condition.

Comment: This line, [label setFrame:button1.frame]; should be [label setFrame:button1.bounds];

Comment: @rdelmar sir, many many thanks to you. (y) (y)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have the striped background as a image and use this code to set button's background image and a title?

```
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stripeImage"]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button1 setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To update the label's properties, you can access it as the button;s titleLabel

```
[button1.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIcolor redColor]];
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but that's not my requirement. Stripes are dynamic by condition. Anyway I got my answer from the comment.